# Google play In-app purchase not detecting the product I have created in developer console

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I am new for in-app purchase in android, I have implemented using [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial)

I have uploaded signed APK with License Key for the app to Alpha Testing, have created In-app products, Included product ID of the in-app product I have created in code.

Google play returns "The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found"

Following is the code I have used:

```
public static final String TAG = "com.some.name";
```

IabHelper mHelper;

```
static final String ITEM_SKU = "com.inapp.ID";



@Override

protected void onStart() {

super.onStart();



String base64EncodedPublicKey = "License";



mHelper = new IabHelper(MainScreenActivity.this, base64EncodedPublicKey);



mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {

public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

if (!result.isSuccess()) {

Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);

} else {

Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");

}

}

});
```

on buy click the following method is called:

```
    public void buyClick(View view) {

Log.e("Buy Clicked", "----------------");



mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(MainScreenActivity.this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,

mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");



}




}
```

Can someone help me with the steps to be followed for successful in-app purchase and what are all the reason for the ERROR message "The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your product id?

Comment: "com.inapp.ID". I have assigned product ID in the second line of code

Answer (score 0):

**In-app Google play process(Rough-outline):**
1. Create APK with License key provided(must) & with your in-app product ID correctly.
2. Upload it to Alpha Testing (For testing).
3. Create in-app Purchase products.
4. Fill all required fields, Upload required screenshots, App graphics wallpaper, etc.,
5. Publish the app, It will take about 24 hours max to get published.
6. Test/Check purchase using the test accounts added.(In the testing APK, Purchase button Trigger with exact product ID you created in Google Play In-app product)

**Problem I faced or mistake/shortcoming I did are,**
1. I tested purchase before publishing the app i.e when the app was in Draft. So it resulted the item you are trying to purchase is not available.
2. I have added non gmail accounts for testing, which resulted some odd error(Unable to connect to server).